# How can I properly configure the g++ include path with mingw64?

Tags: mingw, g++, pacman, mingw64

I have installed msys2/mingw64 because I need the g++ compiler. Now, I want to compile some c++ oce which requires openblas. I have installed the package using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas`. However, compiling the code fails with

> fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory

Clearly, the include path does not contain the headers from openblas which are located at `C:\msys64\mings64\include\openblas`. This is easy to fix by passing `-I<include path>` as an additional argument to `g++`.

Now, I was wondering whether there is an automated way to include include files/headers of installed packages in the `g++` include path. The same problem also holds for libraries.

For example, `pacman` might be able to atomatically append these paths onto some environment variable which `g++` checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I include include files/headers of installed packages in the g++ include path?

> You can set environment variables `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` for include
> directories and `LIBRARY_PATH` for library directories. More
> information can be found in [Environment Variables Affecting GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

Source: [c++ - Add extra include/lib paths to MinGW - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537377/add-extra-include-lib-paths-to-mingw) answer by [Piotr Dobrogost](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

Comment: Will this also work for subdirectories of the paths given there? The problem would be that the openblas dir which contains the headers is a subdirectory of the "include" dir (`C:\msys64\mings64\include`).

Comment: @HerpDerpington It depends what is in the source file. If it says just `cblas.h` then you will needs to include the subdirectory in the environment variable. If it says `openblas\cblas.h` you won't need the subdirectory.